# How do I use func in Linq to Entity select?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities, func

I want a usage like the following, but it gives error if I don't use AsEnumerable.
Why I want it because I'm going to need it in many places.

Is there another way to do this?

```
public static class EntityHelper
{
    public static Func<TABLE1, TABLE2, TABLE2, string> SelectTitle = (trn, acc, parentAcc) => trn.master_id != trn.parent_id ? parentAcc.name : acc.name;
}
```

```
 var query = from trn in context.TABLE1
      join acc in context.TABLE2 on trn.acc_id equals acc.id
      join parentAcc in context.TABLE2 on trn.parent_id equals parentAcc.id                            
      select new {name = EntityHelper.SelectTitle.Invoke(trn,acc,parentAcc)};
```

> System.NotSupportedException: 'LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Invoke(TABLE1, TABLE2,TABLE2)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.'

Comment: Hi Eren, maybe too you can make your question more understandable by giving names in english instead of turkish.  I mean you can use TABLE instead of TABLO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this work using [LinqKit](https://www.nuget.org/packages/LinqKit) nuget.
I changed my code as follows.

```cs
public static class EntityHelper
{
     public static Expression<Func<TABLE1, TABLE2, TABLE2, string>> SelectTitle = (trn, acc, parentAcc) => trn.master_id != trn.parent_id ? parentAcc.name : acc.name;
}
```

```cs
 var query = from trn in context.TABLE1.AsExpandableEF()
      join acc in context.TABLE2 on trn.acc_id equals acc.id
      join parentAcc in context.TABLE2 on trn.parent_id equals parentAcc.id                            
      select new {name = EntityHelper.SelectTitle.Invoke(trn,acc,parentAcc)};
```